# Audacity Nyquist Plugin

Tags: plugins, lisp, audacity

I am playing around with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and have been trying to generate tones with harmonics. Audacity does not seem to support it directly, but you can write a plugin to do it. The plugins are written in Nyquist (a variant of lisp) and there a small tutorial [here](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/help/nyquist). I do not have any experience with lisp and just want to write something similiar to the "Generate -> Tone" feature in Audacity with a harmonics field. Anyone have a simple example for a generate plug-in that I can use as an example? The plugins that come with Audacity are mostly "processing" types and the few "generate" plugins are not very straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Buzz Tone](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/nyquist/buzz.ny)  example from the [Sample](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/nyquistplugins) Nyquist plugins for Audacity(at Sourceforge). I've never coded one of these, yet  this example seems to make sense.

Also see [Touch Tones](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/nyquist/touchtone.ny).